# Initialisation of array char in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, char

Is the below method correct to initialize a char array? I have used this multiple times in my code and running that program in Visual Studio 2015 doesn't show any errors. Whereas when i compile the same program in Visual Studio 2012 i get a lot of errors, mostly with char array initialization.
So, my question is it okay to initialize that way? And is Visual Studio 2012 showing me a false error?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
char arr[10]={0};
```

Comment: what error is it showing you?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. If you're getting any errors, you probably have some  more code than just that line and an earlier error is causing the famous C++ cascade of errors.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 and onwards (which is broadly implemented by Visual Studio 2015 with very few omissions), you can go one stage further and write

`char arr[10] = {};`

This sets every element of `arr` to `'\0'`

I'd be tempted to drop compile support for VS2012 (which doesn't purport to implement the C++11 standard) if you are able to: the C++11 standard is an important leap forward in the development of C++. That said, `char arr[10] = {0};` is valid C++03, your compile errors are due to other errors in you code.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11

`{}`

is used for "Aggregate Initialization"

The aggregates are Arryas, Classes(structs) and unions. It takes out the tedious way of initializing arrays and classes which was the case prior to it. The empty Aggregate Initialization is used for Initializing everything with zero

for example

```
char arr[5] = {}
```

will initialize arr[0] to arr[4] with 0

```
struct s {
    int i;
    int j;
};
struct s s1 = {};
// make s1.i = s1.j = 0;
```

Aggregates can also be used for Initializing with values like

```
char str[] {"Test String"};
// This is equivalent to 
char str[] = "Test String";
```

A simple integer or any other built in data type can also initialized like

```
int val { 123 };
```

// equivalent to 
    int val = 123;

Its also widely used in STL initialization. for example

```
std::array<int, 3> ay{ 1,2,3 };
```